# matlab fill plotting, strange properties

Tags: matlab, plot, fill

*Update: i have replicated the issue in 2014a on a windows 8 machine.*

I am attempting to generate a large number of images of squares at varying fill colors using MATLAB (2014a, OSX Yosemite). I find that the fill command is the easiest way to accomplish this -- i simply set the coordinates of the four corners of the square, and the RGB values of the fill color.

However, it is not working so beautifully. Imagine i just want to make three images, with grayscale values of 0.79, 0.80, and 0.81.

I used this code:

```
figure
for fillvalue = [0.79 0.80 0.81]
%   generate stimulus
    fill([-1 1 1 -1],[-1 -1 1 1],[fillvalue fillvalue fillvalue])

%   set axis properties
    axes('Position',[.005 .005 .99 .99],'xtick',[],'ytick',[],...
        'handlevisibility','off','linewidth',2, 'visible', 'off')
    axis off

%   set figure properties
    set(gcf, 'PaperUnits','points', 'PaperPosition',...
            [0, 0, 50, 50],'papersize',[50, 50])

%   save
    filename =  char([num2str(fillvalue) '.png']);
    print(gcf,'-dpng', filename)
end
```

Here are the files, in order (0.79, 0.80, 0.81):

[image: 0.79]
[image: 0.80]
[image: 0.81]

Matlab has done a decent job on 0.79 and 0.81, but 0.80 is definitely not right. Likewise, i'm not sure about why i only get the border in the lower right corner.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because the default background color for figures is `[.8 .8 .8]`, so for some reason MATLAB creates a white rectangle when you print the figure's content to a file...

Type this:

```
get(0,'DefaultFigureColor')
```

And you will get:

```
ans =

    0.8000    0.8000    0.8000
```

Assigning a color different than the default to the figure seems to work for me (Matlab R2013a on OSX Mountain Lion):

Eg:

```
hFig = figure('Color',[.2 .2 .2]) %// <------  Add a background color
                                               ======================
for fillvalue = [0.79 0.80 0.81]
%   generate stimulus
    fill([-1 1 1 -1],[-1 -1 1 1],[fillvalue fillvalue fillvalue])

%   set axis properties
    axes('Position',[.005 .005 .99 .99],'xtick',[],'ytick',[],...
        'handlevisibility','off','linewidth',2, 'visible', 'off')
    axis off

%   set figure properties
    set(gcf, 'PaperUnits','points', 'PaperPosition',...
            [0, 0, 50, 50],'papersize',[50, 50])

%   save
    filename =  char([num2str(fillvalue) '.png']);
    print(gcf,'-dpng', filename)
end
```

Comment: Oh I forgot about the black borders stuff sorry. That's weird...I'll check it out and get back to you if I find something :)